# undefined symbol when initializing a static constexpr home-made string variable with gcc in debug configuration, C++14

Tags: c++, templates, linker, c++14, undefined-reference

I'm failing to understand a linker error in C++14 with `gcc`.
My purpose was to have a template that exposes a name, according to a non-type template parameter (a kind of compile-time mapping between a value and a string).
Lacking support for `constexpr` string in C++14. I implemented a very basic wrapper around a static plain C string:
In header.h

```cpp
#ifndef HEADER
#define HEADER
#include <cstddef>
#include <ostream>

namespace nConstStr
{
class constStr
{
public:
    constexpr constStr() noexcept = default;
    constexpr constStr(constStr const& str) noexcept :
        _str(str._str), _sz(str._sz)
    {
    }
    template<std::size_t N>
    constexpr explicit constStr(char const (&str)[N]) noexcept :
        _str(str), _sz(N - 1)
    {
    }
    ~constStr() noexcept = default;
    constexpr char operator[](std::size_t const i) const noexcept
    {
        return _str[i];
    }
    constexpr std::size_t size() const noexcept
    {
        return _sz;
    }

private:
    char const* _str = nullptr;
    std::size_t _sz = 0;
};
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, constStr const& str)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i)
    {
        os << str[i];
    }
    return os;
}
}

template<std::size_t I> class dummy final
{
public:
    static constexpr nConstStr::constStr name = nConstStr::constStr{"dummy"};
};

#endif
```

For simplicity, here the string is always the same.
Then I've got a translation unit where I'm using this:
In test.cpp

```cpp
void test() {
    // injecting my overloaded operator<<
    using nConstStr::operator<<;
    std::cout << dummy<42>::name << '\n';
}
```

Which I call from `main`.

When compiling with gcc in C++14 in a debug configuration, I've got the link error:

> src.cpp:8: undefined reference to `dummy<42ul>::name'

[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/46x8s8n9M).

On my machine, yet, it compiles and runs fine in `-O2`.
It also works fine with C++17 or more.

Note, `MSVC` accepts the code but `clang` seems consistent with `gcc` (at least on godbolt, couldn't test locally).

Comment: You need to provide an out of class definition for the static member prior to C++17. The reason is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77764521/12002570).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to C++17 (in which you can declare the `static` members `inline` and `static constexpr` members will be implicitly `inline`) you need to provide an out-of-class definition too:

```cpp
template<std::size_t I>
class dummy final {
public:
    static constexpr nConstStr::constStr name = nConstStr::constStr{"dummy"};
};

// Add this:
template<std::size_t I>
constexpr nConstStr::constStr dummy<I>::name;
```

Note: Since you define the `operator<<` overload in the header file, it should be declared `inline`:

```cpp
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, constStr const& str) {
^^^^^^
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i) {
        os << str[i];
    }
    return os;
}
```

Comment: aren't inline variables C++17 and more? At least my compiler says so.

Comment: @Oersted Yes, I noticed you are on C++14 and updated the answer.

Comment: Thx (and for the note also). I forgot this subtlety about static constexpr variable. But, btw, any idea why the code compiles in -O2 whereas it should not? I suspect that optimization optimizes away the all class (which was designed with this goal in mind), leaving no trace for the linker to complain about. If so, could you complete the answer for the record?

Comment: @Oersted That could be it. Anything I say regarding why it works with certain optimizations would be guesses. I don't know that much about the inner workings of the compilers I'm afraid :-)

Comment: As for inline, according to the standard, from C++17 on, a static constexpr member is implicitly inline. Thus making the variable inline would have been redundant (and as told in the question, the code worked in C++17). Thx again for your answer and comments.

Comment: @Oersted Yes, that is true. I updated the answer to make it clearer. You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that prior to C++17, we need to provide an out of class definition for the `constexpr static` data member. From C++17 onwards the out of class definition is optional. That is why, when you try your program with C++17, it starts working without any linker error.

This can be seen from [static](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static):

> A `constexpr static` data member is **implicitly inline and does not need to be redeclared at namespace scope**. This redeclaration without an initializer (formerly required) is still permitted, but is deprecated.   `(since C++17)`

---

(emphasis mine)

This means that to solve your problem in C++14, you need to add the following out of class definition for the `constexpr static` member in the header file `header.h`.

**header.h**

```
//this is needed prior to C++17 but optional in C++17
template<std::size_t I> constexpr nConstStr::constStr dummy<I>:: name;
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Gr4WY9rha)