# Is there a possibility to create an error at the point where static constexpr variables are used in a const reference?

Tags: c++, g++, c++14

My header only library requires to define float constants in C++14 (g++). The library contains following statement:

```
struct A // POD with constants
{
  static constexpr float a{0.1f};
  // more stuff
}
```

Users use this in statements like

```
void func(const float&);
```

and the call

```
func(A::a);
```

which leads to the linker error

```
my.cpp:(.text+0xaffe): undefined reference to `A::a'
```

How can I change this so the compiler (not the linker) creates an error (or at least a warning) at the place where the constexpr is handed over as const reference?

[Example for testing](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:19,endLineNumber:5,positionColumn:19,positionLineNumber:5,selectionStartColumn:19,selectionStartLineNumber:5,startColumn:19,startLineNumber:5),source:%27%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Avoid+print(const+float%26+v)%0A%7B%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+v+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Astruct+A%0A%7B%0A++++static+constexpr+float+a%7B0.1f%7D%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main(int+argn,+char*+args%5B%5D)%0A%7B%0A++++print(A::a)%3B%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:55.85241730279898,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g132,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B14%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+13.2+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86+msvc+v19.latest%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+13.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:44.14758269720102,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Background information (not required for answering the question):

> End of last year the MISRA coding conventions have been release for C++14 (safety content). Therefore the standard is fixed even though one can foresee that C++17 will be usable soon. The error can easily circumvented by guarding the usage of the constant with convert(A::a) where the function is defined as template T convert(T v) {return v;}. Anonymous enumerations work for integral types (enum{a = 10}; or enum : int{a = 10};). This does not require a definition of any symbol. For development of embedded binaries very often libraries are delivered for integration as static libraries as there are no binders that can do a address relocation. One can hope that the error will be detected by test cases that will have a linker running. However still many times the error will show up for the integrators which then have go back to the developers. My hope was be able to optimize this by having something like a compiler flag or using a template struct with implicit conversion operator (which to my knowledge would require a symbol on his own even if it is inline) to either report warning or an error during compile time or remove the necessity of a symbol at all.

Comment: But it already tells you ``in function `main':``.

Comment: yes, as long as you compile a single small example the linker is able to tell you in what line it happens. Having big projects with static libraries it's not going to work anymore.

Comment: What does the project size have to do with it? Can you construct an example where it doesn't tell you the location?

Comment: Do you consider it actually an error or you want it to be accepted in C++14?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77764287/21691539 and https://godbolt.org/z/vrKMxhs4G

Comment: @Oersted Looks like OP isn't looking for a workaround but a way to make the error tell them the point where the error occurs. Otherwise, there are many duplicates for this.

Comment: I changed the description to highlight that i need the compiler to throw this as the linker in most compilations will not run because people ship static libraries. Therefore the error pops up during integration and not during algorithm development.

Comment: You won't get error in such situation because this is perfectly legal. Passing constexpr variable as a reference isn't any different than passing non-constexpr variable. If you don't provide definition of the variable, your program is malformed and you can expect errors. You can consider switching to c++17, which apparently changes something in this regard?

Comment: I used godbolt in multifile mode https://godbolt.org/z/PWe8MMdPd: the linker error is quiet clear on where the issue is happening (*main.cpp:11: undefined reference to 'A::a'*). By the way it was clear also in OP example (*<source>:15: undefined reference to `A::a'*: source line 15 was were the faulty call happened)

Answer (score 0):

If you require it to be a constexpr you can make it a template argument. Floating point template arguments are allowed since C++20:

```
#include <iostream>

template <float x>
void foo(){
    std::cout << x;
}


int main() {
    constexpr float a = 4.23;
    const float b = 2.1;
    foo<a>(); // ok
    //foo<b>(); // error
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cT3ccGhhM).

Usual considerations concerning precision of floating point values apply. Though to merely call a function and use the value this isnt an issue. Just don't rely on eg `foo<0.3>` and `foo<0.1 + 0.2>` to be the same function.

Comment: I don't think OP is looking for a workaround. More importantly, they're specifically asking for C++14.

Comment: @user12002570 "How can I change this so the compiler..." is asking for a workaround. Though, i  did miss the c++14 tag